# Writing regular expression in PHP to wrap <img> with <div>

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I write a pattern, in PHP so that I can find these variations, which are scattered throughout text coming from the database

```
<div id="attachment_38847" style="width: 1610px" class="wp-caption alignnone"><img src="http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/224157043765335545.jpg" alt="mers"><p class="wp-caption-text">Mers</p></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Something called DOMDocument class in PHP may help with this. Not sure though.